# makefile doesn't import PATH properly

Tags: linux, makefile, build, ubuntu-14.04

I have a simple Makefile. For some reason i is not importing `PATH` properly:

Here is what I get when I run `echo $PATH` in the terminal

`/home/someuser/myfs/opt/pkg/petalinux-v2016.2-final/tools/common/petalinux/bin:/home/someuser/myfs/opt/pkg/petalinux-v2016.2-final/tools/linux-i386/petalinux/bin:/home/someuser/myfs/opt/pkg/petalinux-v2016.2-final/tools/common/petalinux/bin:/home/someuser/myfs/opt/pkg/petalinux-v2016.2-final/tools/linux-i386/microblaze-xilinx-elf/bin:/home/someuser/myfs/opt/pkg/petalinux-v2016.2-final/tools/linux-i386/microblazeel-xilinx-linux-gnu/bin:/home/someuser/myfs/opt/pkg/petalinux-v2016.2-final/tools/linux-i386/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin:/home/someuser/myfs/opt/pkg/petalinux-v2016.2-final/tools/linux-i386/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi/bin:/home/someuser/myfs/opt/pkg/petalinux-v2016.2-final/tools/linux-i386/aarch64-none-elf/bin:/home/someuser/myfs/opt/pkg/petalinux-v2016.2-final/tools/linux-i386/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Here is what I get for a `PATH` when I run `make`

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`

Does anybody know what is going on?

`Makefile` is below and here is my system description

```
uname -a
4.4.0-72-generic #93~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 15:05:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

`Makefile`

```
.PHONY: linux bootimage fsbl dts build-dts

all: linux bootimage

dts: build-dts package bootimage

rootfs: build-rootfs package bootimage

fsbl:
    petalinux-build -c bootloader

clean:
    echo $(PATH)
    petalinux-build -x distclean

linux:
    petalinux-build

build-dts:
    petalinux-build -c device-tree

build-rootfs:
    petalinux-build -c rootfs

package:
    petalinux-build -x package

bootimage:
    petalinux-package --boot --force --fsbl ${BOOT_FSBL_IMAGE} --fpga ${BOOT_BIT_IMAGE} --u-boot=${BOOT_UBOOT_IMAGE} -o ${BOOT_IMAGE}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is what I get for a PATH when I run make
>
> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

Here your make file dont have necessary path file that needed for your programm to run.

Easiest way to do export is like this in the makefile.

`export PATH := bin:$(PATH)`

**Perhaps, something like this.**

```
export PATH := $(shell pwd)/bin:$(PATH)

target:
    mkdir -p ./bin 
    export PATH
    echo $(PATH)
```

or another approach is to export all the path variable add that to your ~/.bashrc, its done, it sets explicitly.

**You can append more path using ":" ,add this line in your ~/.bashrc**

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/your/bin1:~/your/bin2
```

**sample example appending more path in env path :**

```
export PATH=/opt/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/contrib/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin/X11
```

[Information about export:](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I'm trying to understand why `make` is not importing `PATH` properly into its environment? My environment `PATH` looks completely different from what `make` is showing. My question is why